# FFMPEG udp stream to VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, vlc, multicast, unicast

i've been trying to create a transport stream using FFMPEG, when i tried it in VLC it was working immediately, however when i stream from FFMPEG to VLC i can't get it to work, here's my string:

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://ip-of-shoutcast-stream:port?listen -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -vn -f mpegts udp://ip-of-destination-pc:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

In VLC i use the same network source i used when VLC was streaming in the main PC:

```
udp://ip-of-main-pc:1234
```

But it doesn't play or show any errors, the orange bar only goes back and forth endlessly.

What am i doing wrong in the FFMPEG and/or VLC side? It has to be FFMPEG since it's getting moved to a server.

Comment: I've the same problem, did you find any solution?